# How to disable EChart's auto-adjust which happens on disabling one of the series?

Tags: echarts

I have an echart with multiple serieses. If user clicks on one of the legends and enable/disable a series, chart auto adusts (zoom in or zoom out) x and y axis to show optimal axis values.

[image]

How do I disable this behaviour so that chart do not auto-adjust axis when enabling/disabling serieses? I would like both axis to stay at initial values all the time without any change.

My Reserch: I know we can set min and max values on X and Y axis to keep X and Y axis fixed. But in this case, I have to calculate min/max manually across serieses. Any built-in flag or option will be much simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution at last:
I ended up setting min and max for each axis. I had to go through every data series, figure out max and min possible values among all serieses and set it on axis. This avoides above behaviour. (Some of the graphs may have multiple axes, so take that in account).

Here is generic function that can be used on chartOptions object to add min and max values based on data. Data is assumed to be part of each series. It only works on first axis incase of multiple axis.

```
static fixBothAxis(chartOptions) {
    console.log(chartOptions);
    const series = chartOptions.series;
    let maxXAxis = -Infinity,
      minXAxis = Infinity,
      maxYAxis = -Infinity,
      minYAxis = Infinity;
    series.forEach((seriesItem: any) => {
      // dont consider serieses that are related to secondary axis
      if (seriesItem && seriesItem.data) {
        const xSeries = seriesItem.data.map(item => item[0]);
        const ySeries = seriesItem.data.map(item => item[1]);
        maxXAxis = Math.ceil(Math.max(maxXAxis, ...xSeries));
        minXAxis = Math.floor(Math.min(minXAxis, ...xSeries));
        if(seriesItem.yAxisIndex !== 1){
          maxYAxis = Math.ceil(Math.max(maxYAxis, ...ySeries));
          minYAxis = Math.floor(Math.min(minYAxis, ...ySeries));
        }
      }
    });

    /* Make both max and min values "stick to nearest sensible value" */

    const xAxis = Array.isArray(chartOptions.xAxis)
      ? chartOptions.xAxis[0]
      : chartOptions.xAxis;
    const yAxis = Array.isArray(chartOptions.yAxis)
      ? chartOptions.yAxis[0]
      : chartOptions.yAxis;

    if (xAxis && !isNaN(minXAxis) && !isNaN(maxXAxis)) {
      xAxis.min = minXAxis;
      xAxis.max = maxXAxis;
    }
    if (yAxis && !isNaN(minYAxis) && !isNaN(maxYAxis)) {
      yAxis.min = minYAxis;
      yAxis.max = maxYAxis;
    }

    return chartOptions;
  }
```